# Sequel ruby validates_unique case insensitive

Tags: ruby, validation, sequel

I tried to validates uniqueness of couple (:name and :type) with Sequel ORM:

```
def validate
    super    
    validates_unique [:name, :type]
end
```

But Sequel is default to case sensitive. How can I validate this with case insensitive (not care about upcase or downcase)? Like a similar way of ActiveRecord:

`validates_uniqueness_of :name, :case_sensitive => false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not great, but [from the docs](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/ed6a721381e55b1d7301f1f8a79b243f8e7c6e61/lib/sequel/plugins/validation_helpers.rb#L226):

```
   # If you want to do a case insensitive uniqueness validation on a database that
   # is case sensitive by default, you can use:

   validates_unique :column, :where=>(proc do |ds, obj, cols|
     ds.where(cols.map do |c|
       v = obj.send(c)
       v = v.downcase if v
       [Sequel.function(:lower, c), v]
     end)
   end)
```

Comment: Thank you, I can even validate multiple columns:

`validates_unique [:type, :name]`